# Use web-workers in Meteor clientside

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, web-worker, jspdf

I got an meteor app. On clientside I got a heavy calculation which freezes the whole tab in the browser while executing.
So I want to use Web Workers to avoid freezing and to handle the process better (terminating, loading informations percentages etc).

For getting the web workers to work I had to include a selfwritten `webworker.js` in my `package.js`.

**So my main question is: How do I set up web workers in a meteor app (clientside)?**

First I tried following things:

Add a file via `api.addFile()` with bare option.

```
Package.describe({
  name: 'some:name',
  version: '0.0.1',
  // Brief, one-line summary of the package.
  summary: 'Generates PDFs',
  // URL to the Git repository containing the source code for this package.
  git: '',
  // By default, Meteor will default to using README.md for documentation.
  // To avoid submitting documentation, set this field to null.
  documentation: 'README.md'
});

Package.onUse(function(api) {
    api.versionsFrom('1.1.0.2');
    api.use(['mrt:redis@0.1.3'],
    'server',
    {weak: false, unordered: false}
    );
    api.addFiles([
        "vendor/FileSaver.js",
        "vendor/jspdf.debug.js",
        "dcPDF.js"
    ],["client"]);
    api.addFiles([
        "server.js"
    ],["server"]);
    api.addFiles(["pdfProgressWorker.js"],["client"], {bare: true});
    api.export('DCPDF');
});
```

Meteor compresses all files in packages. To set up the workers right, I have to deploy the `webworker.js` as own js-file on clientside. The bare option seems not to work for this case. My js-files cannot call my `webworker.js` if I include the file in that way.

Second try:

I added my `webworker.js` to the `/public` folder.

Problem here: my webworker.js uses some external libaries which I already included in my own package. If I add the webworker.js to the public folder, I have to add all my external js-libaries too, which are all loaded on every site in my meteor app, which slows my whole application down. Not intended, not maintainable, not meteor-style (I think).

Comment: Have you tried the [nerdmed:catiline](https://atmospherejs.com/nerdmed/catiline) package?

Comment: @MichelFloyd: I have, and that did not do anything at all :(